# SwiftUI and MVVM: Is using multiple viewModels in one view 'valid'?

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

This is more a general question: I'm working on my first SwiftUI project and using MVVM for the first time as well. After programming some views I realized that I need for almost each view two different view models. Often it's the view model for the current view and the view model of the previous/mother view. Is this "normal" or is this a hint that I've designed my project wrong and abusing MVVM?

For example:

I have a view where I list all flashcard decks. For this view I have a `decksViewModel`that looks like this:

```
class DeckListViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var decks = [Deck]
    @Published var showDeck = false // this value will be true if i tab on a deck and the deck will shown in a detailed view. This value is checked in the list
    @Published var expandButton = false
    @Published var showDownloadCenter = false
    @Published var showCreateDeck = false
}
```

Now I have a `deckDetailView` for the detailed view of my deck. The `deckDetailViewModel` stores the selected item. But to remove this view I need to change the value of the `showDeck? in` decksViewModel`. So I need to pass this view model as well.

Comment: Accesing parent viewmodel is not unusual, but you can do it in more loosely coupled manner, using events, or service classes injected into your viewmodel. Can you elaborate, why you need to access parent viewmodel?

Comment: I've added an example. Hope it's better understandable now

Comment: No rules and no walls if it works for you and based on public API (to be accepted at AppStore)... don't listen about "normal" - think different.

Comment: @Asperi So would you say my approach in the example is ok? Or is there something where you can see some improvements?

Comment: Passing DeckListViewModel to DeckDetailViewModel is not that bad in this simple example. However, it makes DeckDetailViewModel tightly coupled to DeckListViewModel which makes is harder to test amd impossible to reuse if needed. I would say it’s ok for now, but there are alternative ways of decoupling the viewmodels

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that's a good way to use MVVM.

Instead of storing showDeck in DeckListViewModel, you could just have it as a local @State variable in whatever view you're using it in. Or if you're using a NavigationView, just use a NavigationLink, and there'll be no need for any state variable.

```
struct DecksView: View {
    @ObservedObject var deckListVM = DeckListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(deckListVM.decks) { deck in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DeckDetailView(deckDetailVM: DeckDetailViewModel(deck: deck))) {
                        // some view
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how you implemented your DeckDetailViewModel, just guessing there.

Comment: I don't use a NavigationView, so therefore I need the additional State to check it. That's something I'm wondering also: Is it usual to have a viewModel in a view and some extra single states? I thought everything should be stored in the viewModel. If not, then that's a good solution for me I think!

Comment: it's definitely fine to have extra local states along with your viewModel